# ¿Cómo se llama el ángulo positivo que se forma cuando la recta corta al eje de las X?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, matemáticas

Espero y me puedan ayudar. ¿Cómo se llama el ángulo positivo que se forma cuando la recta corta al eje de las X?

Answer (score 2):

[Muchos](https://www.google.com/search?q=inclinacion%20de%20una%20recta) (incluida [Wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendiente_(matem%C3%A1ticas))) lo llaman **ángulo de inclinación** de la recta.